# bool operation in expression

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream.h>
int main() {
   int choice;
   cin>>choice;
   if (1<=choice<=3) cout<<"good";
   else cout<<"bad";
   return 0;
}
```

How is the bool expression is evaluated? is this expression equal to

```
if ((1<=choice)||(choice<=3))
```

Comment: Associativity of <= is LR(left to right).So ((1<=choice))<=3) this could be the expression.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (1<=choice<=3) cout<<"good";
```

Is like writing:

```
if ((1<=choice)<=3) cout<<"good";
```

Which is always satisfied because `1<=choice` returns 0 or 1 (0 is *false* and 1 is *true*), which is *always* `<=3`.

What you (probably) want to do is:

```
if(1 <= choice && choice <=3)
```

Comment: I think that `(1<=choice<=3)` is always true, for the reason you explained, so your equivalence don't seem correct to me

Comment: Actually, it's the same as `if ( true )`, since `1 <= choice` can only  evaluate to `true` or `false`, which is always less than 3.

Comment: But true is 1 and false is 0 so it is less then 3? but tree is true also! so we get if(true<=true) so its true

Comment: @FinlayLifny No. You get `if(0<=3)` or `if(1<=3)`.

Comment: check my comment on martin answer below Anyway Thanks guys!]

Answer (score 0):

```
(1<=choice<=3)
```

is not equivalent to:

```
(1 <= choice || choice <= 3)
```

but rather:

```
((1 <= choice) <= 3)
```

Which is always going to be true, since int(1 <= choice) is equal to 0 or 1

I assume that what you want is:

```
(1 <= choice && choice <= 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need this.

```
if (1<=choice && choice <=3) cout<<"good";
```